# How to stop retry operation for IBM MQ for any runtime error?

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms, mq

1. We are using the below spring-boot-starter to listen to messages from IBM MQ.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
 <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code snippet

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("inside onMessage body "+message.getBody(String.class));
        int x = 1/0;
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

2. Suppose we are getting exceptions while listening, this piece of code will keep on retrying. So I want to put a limit to retry-mechanism.
3. Is there any way to stop the retry operation after it reaches certain limit.
4. I am using the below listener configuration.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsManualAckListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,                                                            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer config) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    containerFactory.setSessionTransacted(false);
    containerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    containerFactory.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff(2000, 2));
    config.configure(containerFactory,connectionFactory);
    return containerFactory;
}
```

Comment: The number of redelivers before moving the message to the dead letter queue is configured on the messaging system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring How to Limit number of retry in Message listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242968/spring-how-to-limit-number-of-retry-in-message-listener)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Is there a way to configure this behaviour on server itself similar to temporal workflow.